# What does "P-wave" mean when referring to a particle?

Tags: particle-physics, terminology

In scattering theory, P wave means $l=1$, where $l$ is the azimuthal quantum number. However, what does P wave mean when referring to particle states? For example, in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9208254) (arXiv link), the authors are talking about *P-wave charmonia states*. What does that mean?

More specifically, I understand that in some sort of potential model, solved using Schroedinger equation for example, there will be states that may be labeled by $n$=something, $l=1$. But here, the article says P-''wave'' charmonia! What is this wave?

Comment: They are talking about *charmonium* which is the meson $c\bar{c}$, see [this Wikipedia article on the J/$\psi$ meson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J/psi_meson) (this is mentioned in the opening paragraph of the linked paper as well).

Comment: Kyle Kanos - thanks for the edit and yes, they are talking about charmonium. I have read that wiki article, but that doesn't answer the wave part. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I see no reason to think that it is *not* [spectroscopic notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectroscopic_notation) they are using.

Comment: Kyle Kanos - You are right. Even the wiki article says it is the spectroscopic notation. But I am not understanding the meaning of wave, I get the P part. This wave notation is very common while refering to these states, most people call it P wave charmonia. But I have not come across any occasion where it is explained what the meaning of this ''wave'' is. Why not just charmonia P state?

Comment: An off-the-cuff guess: it's the wave function for the P-state. I'm not much of a particle physicist, so I'll have to leave an actual answer to someone else.

Comment: Kyle Kanos - I'm not too sure about that. In non-relativistic treatments, one does talk about the wave function, but in general in particle Physics, single particle wavefunctions are problematic aren't they? (e.g. in the simple Klein Gordon, or Dirac equation solutions etc.) So, wave standing for wavefunction does not look right to me, especially since notation would be general and not specific to NR. But nevertheless, thanks for your participation in this. You certainly improved my question.

Comment: Recall that the s, p, d, f naming scheme originally came from atomic spectroscopy not from scattering theory. It applies just fine to bound systems such as charmonium without any need to talk about wave functions. The *state* has such-and-so angular momentum. The appellation "p-wave" is just habit.

Comment: @dmckee - Thanks. That makes sense. But how did that ''habit'' come into existence at all. What is so wavy about any particle state in the first place? That was the reason why I refered to scattering theory here - at least there are waves over there!

Comment: I don't know from personal experience or from primary testimony, but I assume the "wave" usage was popularized in the scattering domain. It's just that the existence of angular momentum quantum numbers that have to be described applies to all states, bound or otherwise.

Comment: @dmckee - Thanks, so now we agree that there has to be a scattering context (rest of it was fine right from the start). But that's precisely what I don't get - if it is a particle with $l=1$, produced in a scattering experiment (like all are), why does it have to INHERIT the ''wave'' label from that context?

Comment: "Wave" doesn't have any importance. It's not a marker for something that you have to do or remember of calculate. It means the same thing as "state of the system with angular momentum <l == 1>" only it's shorter. You could say "l-shell", too, but it would be unusual.

Comment: @dmckee - Saw your comment today. Thank you. If you post this as an answer, I can accept and up vote.

Comment: Related question on Astronomy: http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/6257/

Comment: Hi @HDE226868. That was me only, while I was still unregistered. I landed up on that site first, saw some ques which looked interesting, posted the question, didn't get an answer, and was disappointed. (I now know answers don't come up immediately, but back then I thought they do.) A little later, I landed up here and thought the same is more likely to be answered here. So, I signed up, and while I never got an "answer", dmckee answered it with his comments. Somehow, in the middle of all of this, I never checked at how it fared over there. It got an answer after 9 days!

Comment: @UserAnonymous Huh, weird. You should be able to contact SE and get your accounts merged, if you want.

Comment: @HDE226868 - I think my interests are better suited to this site than Astronomy. I won't even even have any good question to contribute there. Besides, if I create another UserAnonymous account there, I won't have upvoting and commenting privileges, and asking fake questions just to get enough reputation to be able to do that doesn't make sense to me. Could you please upvote that answer and thank Rob on my behalf? Or post a link to this question here, in a comment? Thanks.

Comment: @UserAnonymous Already did, when he posted it. But merging your accounts will mean that you can deal with something that comes up cross-site. All that would happen would be that you can access both accounts, and they'd have the same name. And you'll soon get those privileges, because you're close to getting the association bonus.

Answer (score 2):

The states of charmonium are treated as bound states of a charmed quark ($c$) and its anti-quark ($\bar{c}$). Since the binding energy of the $c-\bar{c}$ system is relatively small, compared to the rest energy of the charmed quarks, it is a reasonable starting point to analyze the states using the non-relativistic Schroedinger equation with a potential derived from QCD (Coulomb-like at short distances, linear at large distances to keep the quarks confined). As already commented on, the s, p, d, f naming scheme for states of definite orbital angular momentum goes back to the days of atomic spectroscopy -- it was also used in the study of the nucleon-nucleon system (both for the deuteron and for the scattering states).